# Two questions about axiomatic rank of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, model-theory, universal-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $V=Var(G)$ be the variety generated by $G$. Suppose the axiomatic rank of $V$ is $n$. Let $Id(V)$ be the set of all identities of $V$.

1- Can we say that every element of $Id(V)$ is equivalent to some identity of the form
$$ w(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\approx 1?$$

2- Let $G$ be finite. Can we prove that the axiomatic rank of $V$ is finite without using the fact that $V$ is finitely based?

Comment: What is axiomatic rank? Number of identities or variables?

Comment: Minimum number of variables.

Comment: For question 1 what do you mean by equivalent.

Comment: For question 2 Mark Sapir proved a finite semigroup is finitely based iff it has finite axiomatic rank in your sense. He may have used that all finite groups are finitely based though. So most likely the answer is no.

Comment: Let $w(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\approx1$ and $w^{\prime}(y_1, \ldots, y_m)\approx 1$ be two identities in $V$. We say that these identities are equivalent if for any group $G$, we have $G\vDash (w\approx 1)$ iff $G\vDash (w^{\prime}\approx 1)$.

Comment: To question 1 the answer is obviously negative. Just consider the trivial variety, it has finite axiomatic rank but satisfies *all* identities.

Comment: The trivial variety has axiomatic rank 1, right? for $n\geq 2$, the free group $F_m$ embeds in $F_n$, this convince me that there may be a way of expressing an $m$-variable identity in terms of $n$ variables.

Comment: @M.Shahryari, no way. Consider the variety of abelian groups. It satisfies the metabelian law $[[x,y],[z,t]]=1$ or the nilpotency law $[[x,y],z]=1$. Do you believe that these laws are equivalent to two-variable laws?

Comment: Thank you Anton, the answer it correct, but let me to explain exactly what I need: let the axiomatic rank of $V$ be $n$ and $M=\{ w\in F_n:\ V\vDash w\approx 1\}$. Now, if $v\approx 1$ is an identity of $V$ with $m>n$ variables, then is it true that $v\in \langle M^{F_m}\rangle$ (the normal closure)? In your example $v=[[x,y],[z,t]]$ belongs to the normal closure of $w=[x,y]$ in $F_4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning question 2: by a result of Birkhoff, a finite algebra (of finite type) is finitely based if and only if it is of finite axiomatic rank (see e.g. Thm 4.2. in the book of Burris-Sankappanavar). So the question essentially asks for a new proof of the Oates-Powell-Theorem.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Just can't understand one point: the theorem of Birkhoff concerns all finite algebras of finite type and as I see it is published 1935. In the comments Benjamin Steinberg says that it is proved for finite semigroups by Mark Sapir (may be on 1988). I can't download the paper of Sapir, so I don't know actually what he did.